# Real function with complex antiderivative $\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Consider this indefinite integral (I'm interested in the interval $x>0$):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$

By substitution:

$$u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}, \qquad x=\frac{1}{2u \sqrt{u^2-1}}$$

We get a closed form antiderivative:

> $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\sqrt{2} \tanh^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}} +C$$

Now the inverse hyperbolic tangent is real only for the argument in $(-1,1)$. But in our case the argument for all real $x$ is $ > 1$.

> How can the function with real values on $x>0$ have a complex antiderivative?

---

**Edit**

To be clear, this is *the correct* antiderivative. I.e. by differentiating it we get the function under the integral.

> How would you explain this without appealing to complex analysis, i.e. branches? This is a real valued function for positive $x$, so this can be given as an assignment to a first year calculus student for example

---

**Edit 2**

The derivation of the antiderivative after the substitution:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\sqrt{2} \int \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\sqrt{2} \int u \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=x(2u^2-1)$$

$$dx=-x\frac{2u^2-1}{u(u^2-1)}du$$

$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\frac{du}{u(u^2-1)}=\frac{du}{u(1-u^2)}$$

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\sqrt{2} \int \frac{du}{1-u^2}=\sqrt{2} \tanh^{-1} u$$

Comment: you have to be careful with the branch of the square root in your substitution $x=\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}$

Comment: Essentially the function defining your substituin is not real on all $\mathbb{R}$ but only in the specific domain namely $(-1,1)$. Choosing another branch of the square root gives you a real function also on other intervalls

Comment: Or in a more practical sense:  For $|x|>1$ substitute $x=\frac{1}{2u \sqrt{1-u^2}}$

Comment: @tired, I see, this makes sesne. But essentially, the imaginary part I've got is a constant, right?

Comment: indeed yes..otherwise your antiderivative wouldn't be correct

Comment: look up the actual formula for arctanh involving log, log negative number generates a constant imaginary component, and this vanishes into a constant of integration - or also you could say it vanishes when differentiating the anti-drivative

Comment: You should have given the whole derivation, at least to the point where you introduce the $\text{artanh}$. It is likely that you should have used an $\text{arcoth}$ instead, they differ in the domain and the sign of the derivative.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: yep, you could as well have integrated as $\coth^{-1}u$, giving purely real values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you, I see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}>
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=1
$$
Assuming your substitutions are correct, the integral becomes
$$
\sqrt{2}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1-u}+\frac{1}{1+u}\right)\,du=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\log\left|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right|+c
$$
You cannot apply the substitution $u=\tanh v$, as $u>1$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it immediately clear. The correct antiderivative is the logarithm of absolute value, while mine was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer

$$\text{arctanh} = \frac12 \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

consider $\ln(x)$ where $x < 0 $

$$\ln(x) = \ln(|x| (-1))=$$
$$ = \ln(x) + \ln(-1)= \qquad  \text{(properties of logs)} $$
$$= \ln(x) + \ln(e^{i \pi}) $$
$$= \ln(x) + i \pi$$

so in your integration, the log of a negative number generates a constant $i \pi$ (or $ki \pi$ where $k$ is a constant)- this just disappears into the constant of integration, similar to other constants that can be generated and absorbed in integrations involving inverse hyperbolic functions

Comment: Thank you, and I figured this out too, but we don't have complex constants in real analysis. The logarithms are not defined for negative values. We can't hide this behind the constant without using complex analysis. This is what I'm confused about

Comment: it's similar to justifying integral 1/x = log |x| , you could also put absolute value in your answer I believe - I've always felt that many people don't really understand why int 1/x has absolute value in it (other than to make it work)